# What is defining the routing table?

Tags: networking, startup, routing

Some script, somewhere, is defining the routing table for a Ubuntu 16.04 system and we can't figure out what.

It isn't in `/etc/udev/`, `/etc/network/`, `/etc/systemd/`, `/etc/init.d/` or any other likely location.

The question is whether anyone knows which script or configuration file is doing this, or how one might figure this out.

One hint is that the entries revealed by running `ip route show` reflect the interface names created with some udev rules, and a virtual bridge (virbr0) otherwise created, so whatever script this is, is run after these definitions and recognizes them.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts, no searchable solutions seem to exist.